# Google Maps Marker with dynamic image inside marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to add an image inside of a google maps marker (not info window).  Essentially I want an avatar as the marker, but still want to retain the marker icon.

Is there any way to do something like this in gmaps 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like the [Marker With Label](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.5/) class what you're looking for? It adds a DOM object to a marker which you can place an image in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactely what you wanna do. In the past i need an marker with number on it (to display how many elements each place has). I released it as an open source code and you can find it http://zeetha.com/open/iconsharp/

Does it help you?

Comment: That is very nice and would be useful.  I am not using php for this application (python).